# typescript infer keyword does not return expected result because of optional property that is not present

Tags: reactjs, typescript

## TLDR:

```js
interface CoreProps {prop1: number;}
interface AnchorProps {prop2: number}

type Feature<P extends object> = { state?: (state: object, props: P) => object | void; };
type FeaturePT<P extends object> = { state?: (state: object, props: P) => object | void; propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P>; };

type t = [Feature<CoreProps>, Feature<AnchorProps>] extends Feature<infer S>[] ? S : never;
// type: CoreProps | AnchorProps - great

type tPT = [FeaturePT<CoreProps>, FeaturePT<AnchorProps>] extends Feature<infer S>[] ? S : never;
// type: never - why?
```

## DEMO

[demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsoQApXQBwGdkBvAWAChll898BGALmRAFcBbAI2gG5KBfSqEixEKAIIgEAC0y4CxclRp0ATMzZdeAypTABPfCgBiEOGFZYAPNmQQAHpBAATYuk4ArCAjAA+ZAC8pMiEYOYQAPzMABSh4czuXj4ANCoKzNgAlIH+id5gyAA+yABu6MDOyPx8FAZGyKbmljgAKjZ2jhAubp75-kFK1HGQUcixYZAJvSlpRBnZAbnTBcVlFTXUtAQthhCEowDqZgDWAGpwADYV5sDoIACycPg2vjXVuhQXEAUYWMyNFmsvxwdEIr2QAHoIchgOx8F92F0JrcQCx0AUsF8SnBwJQvgVJDJMIR-mZARArITZFB5ERwVCYXCEUibnc0RiIFicWAPgzWGBgFcDHpdsgAKogFEtdAASXA0EI+RRVjF-TGYo6TlcyBx+mQETGx2YYoW-jWlQ0EBK0GyDi1xGiRphIBg0GQMtNpXKlQNMuQlutUBqdRQAHNvrTCFYWmqJVLZfKoIqfMqWpqutqAc0rKBXVBkABlXwAbQAuvrC-6WFboK8PvjkAh0HC7kiAEKsQXON1BaPp7oNMnZ3Ul0u+aKuppYEnIFqZZgAJTMPgAdMZUFZw2BI9HfP1-INkFhAaiSPwdcRdW8apQmyBQsh7voMC2QEjAo3m-hW+AO13oNExbAqkVLEqWmQ1AyIboDAj7Pl+P4FAAtNQS6IGAa4bqBNKgsgABkaCYCCCj+MgKEOEgFxfLiFB4t8hFYNgLSklOrRWMCkb0tCsLwhAiLgKyqIgOiR6cla3J0QSUjUoQTEseSTGUtJciglxjK8fxyJssJHJcjRd4PpO5KyWmQRAURTEgcpSZMaWNQGQUT4vt+b7gExH5Nq+7adhc3ZQBOQ7TkxEGUFBuwwXBzmIWRyBoau65WKwIDHMJADuIC+EAA)

copy to your IDE - it should work

## Details

I understand what the problem is, but I have no idea how to fix it.

let's say I have objects which represent features, and function which receive a list of these objects and return a new React component constructed of those features - with types being inferred from the list of objects.

#### infer with no optional property:

first let's define `Feature` type:

```js
type Feature<P extends object> = {
  state: (state: object, props: P) => object | void;
};
```

let's define dummy 2 features:

```js
interface CoreProps {
  prop1: number;
}
interface AnchorProps {
  prop2: number;
}

let Core: Feature<CoreProps>; // implementation not relevant
let Anchors: Feature<AnchorProps>; // implementation not relevant
```

these features would be pass to a function `componentBuilder` which return a new React Component:

```js
// utility
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (k: infer I) => void ? I : never;
type getProps<T> = UnionToIntersection<T extends Feature<infer S>[] ? S : never>;

let componentBuilder = <T extends Feature<any>[]>(features: T): React.FC<getProps<T>> => {
  return {} as any;
};
```

test this:

```js
const MyComponent = componentBuilder([Core,Anchors])
// typeof MyComponent -  React.FC<AnchorProps & CoreProps>  - excellent
```

so far so good.

#### infer with optional property:

let's add an optional property to `Feature`: `propTypes` which should also be weakly validated to fit the type of the given properties `P`

```js
type FeaturePT<P extends object> = {
  state: (state: object, props: P) => object | void;
  propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P>;
};
```

Oops:

```js
let CorePT: FeaturePT<CoreProps>; // implementation not relevant
let AnchorsPT: FeaturePT<AnchorProps>; // implementation not relevant
const featuresPT = [CorePT, AnchorsPT];
const MyComponentPT = componentBuilder(featuresPT);
// typeof MyComponent - React.FC<unknown>

// and why unknown? because:
type t = typeof featuresPT extends Feature<infer S>[] ? S : never; // never - because 'propTypes' is not given so WeakValidationMap<P> requirement is not met
```

typescript no longer infers the parameter T of the generic interface React.FC because `propTypes` was not given so `WeakValidationMap<P>` requirement is not met.
if I will add the propType property to the Feature objects typescript will return the correct result.

well, this property is optional for a reason so `typeof featuresPT extends Feature<infer S>[] ? S : never` should return the first branch `S` and not the second branch `never`

What can I do to get around it?

Comment: Please share reproducible example. You did not provide `XarrowFeature`.

Comment: Demo is still not reproducible :(

Comment: I'm sory but you cannot import things (like react) in the playground so I'm working on it, if you will copy the text to your IDE it should work

Comment: It is possible to import React into playground, no worries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after few days a accidentally found the problem: instead of :

```js
T extends XarrowFeature<infer S>[] ? S : never>
```

I needed:

```js
T extends Array<infer S> ? (S extends XarrowFeature<infer K> ? K : never) : never
```

the first sometimes worked, and sometimes(when you use generic type T in multiple properties) did not worked and returned unknown.